# Storing a boolean or int and check/change it's value after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to store a boolean or int someplace where I can check it after the page has loadedd, so that I can change the boolean to false after the page has loaded (via an `a` link).

I know you can put this as hidden text or hidden radio buttons on the page, but thats really ugly...

I was also thinking about using HTML 5's Client-side Storage.

So far I have this:

But obviously this doesn't work when I check stopOnMouseOut later on in the script it will always return true...

```
stopOnMouseOut = true;

    var stopSoundsVar = document.getElementById("stop_sounds");
    stopSoundsVar.onclick = function() {
        // toggle boolean
        if (stopOnMouseOut == true) {
            stopOnMouseOut = false;
        }else {
            stopOnMouseOut = true; 
        }
        //alert(stopOnMouseOut);
        return false;
     }
```

Are there any best practices towards doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated in your question, you could use localStorage (persistent on browser loads) or sessionStorage (which only lasts the life of the page -- new windows are new sessions).

Using localStrorage (or sessionStorage) is as easy as:

```
localStorage.key = "value";
```

You can only store strings in DOM storage, so you may have to compare the boolean you retrieve back out as `"true"` or `"false"` rather than just `true` or `false`. Alternatively, you can convert the data to JSON, and parse the JSON back out.

Saving data with localStorage: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/

Compatibility: http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the condition a bit:

```
var stopOnMouseOut = true,
    stopSoundsVar = document.getElementById("stop_sounds");

stopSoundsVar.onclick = function() {
    stopOnMouseOut = !stopOnMouseOut;
    return false;
 }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bHmyj/

Comment: Thanks, I did not know ! would reverse a boolean. But my original question is still not answered.